# How to tell if a InstrumentedAttribute is a relation in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a sqlalchemy model class

```
class Table(Base):
  __table__name = 'table'
  col1 = Column(...)

  rel = relationship(...)
```

If you look at *Table*, both *col1* and *rel* are of type `InstrumentedAttribute`. How can I distinguish these two? I tried to look into their attributes. But there are too many...and there's no document about this matter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the type of [`Table.<column>.property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/internals.html?highlight=columnproperty#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute.property) which can commonly be either instance of ColumnProperty or RelationshipProperty:

```
>>> type(Table.col1.property)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty'>
>>> type(Table.rel.property)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.relationships.RelationshipProperty'>
```