# sqlalchemy getting type of field for synonym and relationships

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relationship, synonym

I have a SQL Alchemy ORM where I have regular columns, synonyms and relationships.

```
class Table1(Base):
   regular_field = Column("RegularField", Integer)
   field = Column("TestField", String)
   field_synonym = synonym('field')
   relation_type = relationship("Table2", back_populates="Table1")
```

When I retrieve an object from the DB using a session, how can I loop over the returned object and return regular fields that do not have synonyms, skip fields that have synonyms, the synonyms themselves and skip the relationships? So for the above, it should only return

```
    regular_field, field_synonym
```

and skip

```
    field (since it has a synonym called field_synonym) 
    relation_type (which is a relationship).
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on the instance alone, you'll need to look at the class attributes for this to work. If you look up the attribute on the class with the same name you can either check the `type` or do an `isinstance` check on the class-attribute.

### Example, given you have a `table1` instance

```
>>> table1.__class__.regular_field.__class__.__mro__
(sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute,
 sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute,
 sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces._MappedAttribute,
 sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces._InspectionAttr,
 sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.PropComparator,
 sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators,
 sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators,
 object)
```

You can then check for a particular class like this

```
field = table1.__class__.field_synonym
if isinstance(field, sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.propertyProxy):
    # overwriting vars is bad style, just for illustration purposes!
    field = field.original_property
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way to introspect which field something is a synonym of? I can identity synonyms but not what they are synonyms of.

Comment: Use the `dir` function to see which attributes are defined on the `synonym` (or any other) object. This way you can figure out even internal, undocumented methods/attributes. Using this I figured out that there is a `original_property` attribute on the `propertyProxy` which is instantiated by `synonym`. The destination probably has a `key` property (as have most SQLAlchemy ORM properties) which gives you it's name.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the synonyms, but here is a way to check if an object attribute is a relationship (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26572422)):

```
table = Table1()
mapper_prop = type(table).relation_type.property
# Use getattr if you have a dynamic attribute name
# mapper_prop = getattr(type(obj), key).property
if isinstance(mapper_prop, RelationshipProperty):
    print('I am a relationship')
```

Comment: You can define it in more details

Comment: What do you mean by "define it in more details" ?